# Added ( to CreateUserWizard control ) additional wizard steps after CreateUserWizardStep and CompleteWizardStep, but they don't get displayed

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I'd like to add ( to CreateUserWizard control ) additional wizard steps after CreateUserWizardStep and CompleteWizardStep, but when clicking on ContinueButton in CompleteWizardStep, instead of being forwarded to next wizard step, nothing happens! What am i doing wrong?

thanx

EDIT:

```
        <asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" runat="server" 
        oncreateduser="CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser">
        <WizardSteps>
            <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="CreateUserWizardStep1" runat="server">
            </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
            <asp:CompleteWizardStep ID="CompleteWizardStep1" runat="server">
            </asp:CompleteWizardStep>
            <asp:WizardStep StepType="Finish">
            uh       
            </asp:WizardStep>
        </WizardSteps>
    </asp:CreateUserWizard>
```

Comment: Did you make any progress on this? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you edited the Template of the intermdiate wizrd step in your Control. You must also tell the intermediate step about when and show to go to previous step and next step. Can you put some code in this case ? mark-up of your createuserwizrd control ?

Comment: I've edited my original post and put CreateUserWizard's markup code in there. Anyways, as far I know CompleteWizardstep doesn't have StepType attribute, so I'm not sure how I could inform it that another step follows and thus it should add Next button so we can proceed to the next step?!

Comment: ok, can you please elaborate what do you want to do in the intermediate step ?

Comment: I assume by intermediate step you are referring to  CompleteWizardStep?! I just want it to display confirmation message and then enable us ( by providing Next button ) to continue to the next step

Answer (score 1):

If you want your `asp:WizardStep` to be called you have to use the `<CustomNavigationTemplate>` in your `asp:CompleteWizardStep` and put the next button in there - it will then call your `asp:WizardStep`